# Google Tag Manager Standard eCommerce

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, e-commerce, google-tag-manager, google-datalayer

I'm attempting to setup Standard eCommerce in Google Tag Manager.

However, Google Analytics is not receiving my transaction data; I'm trying to push the data through Google Tag Manager's `dataLayer` to Google Analytics - but when I reload my receipt page nothing gets reported in my Google Analytics dashboard.

Here's the code I wrote: (this executes **above** the GTM tag)

```
window.dataLayer = window.dataLayer || [];
@*Send the receipt information to Google*@
        dataLayer.push(
            {
                'transactionId': '@Model.StudentCheckoutReceiptId',
                'transactionAffiliation': 'AcmeStudios',
                'transactionRevenue': @Model.Total,
                'transactionShipping': '@Model.ShippingOptionPurchased.ToString()',
                'transactionProducts': {
                    'id': '@Model.StudentCheckoutReceiptId',
                    'name': '@packageOption',
                    'price': @Model.Total,
                    'quantity': 1
                }
            });
// GTM include
....
// End GTM include
```

The `dataLayer` looks like this after the page loads:
[image]

However, none of the information gets received in Google Analytics:
[image]

Here is my Google Tag Manager configuration:
[image]
[image]
[image]

The URL of my receipt page:

`https://acmestudios.com/receipt/1aa2726f-9881-43b4-ba42-34a5510d8e67`

What am I missing?

Comment: can you put your tag manager into developer mode and post screenshots to show that the tag triggered?

Answer (score 0):

I setup everything correctly except the dataLayer object was incorrect; if you don't follow the format and variable names that Google specifies *exactly* then it won't work; you also need to make sure that any `Required` parameter is passed in. Here's what my dataLayer looks like now:

```
@*Send the receipt information to Google*@
dataLayer.push(
    {
        'transactionId': '@Model.ReceiptId',
        'transactionAffiliation': 'AcmeProducts',
        'transactionTotal': @Model.Total,
        'transactionShipping': '@Model.ShippingOptionPurchased.ToString()',
        'transactionProducts': [{
            'name': '@packageOption',
            'sku': 'none',
            'price': @Model.Total,
            'quantity': 1
        }]
    });
```